# Making [ <-SPACE-> ] accepted and not accepting reserved words in regex java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to make a Java regex checker of a valid variable declaration. Okay so I have the following code variables:

```
private static final String STRING_ARRAY_DATA_TYPE = "((String\\s*\\[\\s*\\]\\s*)"+STRING_VARIABLE+"|"+
                                                "(String\\s+"+STRING_VARIABLE+"\\s*\\[\\s*\\]\\s*))";
private static final String STRING_VARIABLE = "[$|_|[a-zA-Z]][$|_|\\w]*";
private static final String STRING_ARRAY_VALUES = "((" + STRING_VALUE + ",\\s*)*" + STRING_VALUE + "\\s*)*";
private static final String ASSIGNMENT = "\\s*=\\s*";
private static final String END_OF_STATEMENT = "\\s*;+\\s*";
```

And I have this function:

```
private static boolean checkStringArray(String text) {
    return text.matches(STRING_ARRAY_DATA_TYPE + END_OF_STATEMENT) ||
            text.matches(STRING_ARRAY_DATA_TYPE + "\\s+" + ASSIGNMENT +
                    "((new String\\[\\s*-?\\d+\\s*\\])|(new String\\[\\]\\{" + STRING_ARRAY_VALUES + "\\})|(\\{" + STRING_ARRAY_VALUES + "\\}))" + END_OF_STATEMENT);
}
```

So I have two questions:

1. How do I make my regex not accept certain reserved words in Java, say for example `true` and `false`?
2. I've been searching stuff but really haven't found answer as to why it is not accepting this input: `String [        ] myString;`

Comment: Give us examples with input and expected output

Comment: @PascalHeraud oh yeah I forgot to mention I'm trying to make a Java identifier declaration using regex. So as you can see, I have 2 questions. For #1, say for example "int true;" should not be accepted because true is a reserved word. For #2, I've found out that String [           ] myString; should be accepted, but my code is not doing so.

Comment: The code you're giving does not compile. STRING_VARIABLE is defined after it's used (ok easy) and you don't define STRING_VALUE. Please also give an test scenario including positive and negative example and what you expect instead of what you get. Code worth thousands words...

Answer (score 0):

To match special characters, escape it :

```
private static final String STRING_VARIABLE = "\\[$|_|[a-zA-Z]][$|_|\\w\\]*";
```

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that sir but I'm quite puzzled why it's not working if I do String [         ] myString; In the STRING_ARRAY_DATA_TYPE variable I have, I placed \\[\\s*\\] but it's not working as expected.